# Function defined as $f(x) = x^2 + 3 $ Find $f( [-3, 5])$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

The answer given is $f([-3,5]) = [3, 28]$

I get that when you plug in $5, 5^2 + 3 = 28$

However I am not sure how you get $3$, because $-3^2 + 3 = 12$

Am I missing something?

Comment: The endpoints of $f\left([-3,5]\right)$ are not simply $f(-3)$ and $f(5)$, because $f$ is not increasing on the whole interval. It attains its maximum at $f(5)$ and its minimum at $f(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. So then how would I define $f[3, 5]$ would it be $[12, 28]$, because 3 is higher than 0?

Comment: On that interval $f$ is increasing. So we'd have $f[3,5]=[f(3),f(5)]$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the min and max of $f$ on $x\in[-3,5]$, which doesn't necessarily have to be at endpoints. They can also lie on critical points, where $f'(x) = 0$ or is undefined. Here $f'(x)=2x$, which is $0$ at $x=0$. So the minimum and maximum could be located at $x=-3$, $x=0$, or $x=5$. Now just check,

$$ f(0) < f(-3) < f(5) $$

so the range $f([-3,5]) = [f(0),\ f(5)] = [3, 28]$ .

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
f(0) &= 0^2 + 3
\\
&= 3
\end{align}$$

$0$ has a smaller magnitude than $-3$.

Comment: More to the point, $0$ is between $-3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2+3$ is a parabola, precisely a $'\bigcup'$ shape 3 units above the $x$ axis.

Therefore, it makes sense that $x=0$ has the minimum $y$ value, and that $x=-3$ would be on the left half, and have a higher value. So this is why we need $x=0$ as it is the lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\;-3 \le x \le 0 \implies 0 \le x^2 \le 9\;$ and $\;0 \le x \le 5 \implies 0 \le x^2 \le 25\,$. Therefore $-3 \le x \le 5 \implies 0 \le x^2 \le 25\,$, then just add $\,3\,$ to all terms to get $\,3 \le x^2+3 \le 28\,$.